# UIWebView shows white bar at top and bottom when scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIWebView on top of a UIImage. When I scroll on the UIWebView, two white bars appear. 1, at the very top of the iPad window (ie the top of the UIImage, which is just a background image) and 2, at the top of the UIWebView. The UIIMage is in a XIB but the WebView is done programmatically as shown here:

```
mainWebView = [[[CustomWebview alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(59, 0, 650, 1024)] retain];
[(UIScrollView*)[mainWebView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[(UIScrollView*)[mainWebView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

[mainWebView        setOpaque:NO];
[mainWebView        setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[backgroundImage    addSubview:mainWebView];
[mainWebView        setDelegate:self];
```

The same pattern repeats itself at the bottom of the iPad. One white bar at the bottom of the WebView and another at the very bottom of the UIImage.

See photos and a 20 second video: (can't take screenshots while scrolling)
[image: two white bars]
[image: no white bars]

20 second video:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1392139/IMG_0601.MOV

I'd love to find a fix for this, already spent many hours on it and it's my last bug to fix in order to ship!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the "white bars"? It's difficult to imagine what you are referring to. Thanks

Comment: hmmm... "Subclassing Notes \ The UIWebView class should not be subclassed." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The movie doesn't open. To help find the issue, try to give all parts a distinct color: VC background red, background image blue, webview background green, webview content background yellow. Then make new screenshots, which will hopefully reveal a bit more. I also wonder what would happen if you (temporarily) dropped the subclass and would just use a plain `UIWebView`. What does your `CustomWebView` do exactly?

Comment: oh and one more warning: accessing subviews of UIWebView directly has a high chance of randomly breaking on iOS updates. You can make it a little bit safer by looping through the subviews and taking the first UIScrollView you find.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the content you are loading?  It's possible those white bars are from the HTML.

Comment: I used the plain UIWebView instead of the custom class, and it's working great now. MVDS if you provide an answer I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that using a customwebview was giving me problems. I removed the custom class and it fixed the problem.